# Geopandas geom_almost_equals method gives wrong output

Tags: geospatial, geopandas

I have 2 geodata frames.

geoframe1

```
MULTILINESTRING((-0.87131 52.25771, -0.87144 52.25763, -0.87126 52.25756, -0.87146 52.25747, -0.87159 52.25756))
MULTILINESTRING((-0.87180 52.25758, -0.87167 52.25760, -0.87160 52.25767, -0.87148 52.25769, -0.87141 52.25774))
MULTILINESTRING((-0.87190 52.25757, -0.87185 52.25767, -0.87171 52.25775, -0.87151 52.25777, -0.87151 52.25777))
```

geoframe2

```
MULTILINESTRING((-0.87131 52.25771, -0.87144 52.25763, -0.87126 52.25756, -0.87146 52.25747, -0.87159 52.25756))
MULTILINESTRING((-0.87190 52.25757, -0.87185 52.25767, -0.87171 52.25775, -0.87151 52.25777, -0.87151 52.25777))
```

before taking up, geometry wise, both the sets are exactly equal. to check "geom_almost_equals" method, i removed one linestring from geoframe2 and executed the method.

```
features_equal = geoframe1.loc[geoframe1.geom_almost_equals(geoframe2, decimal=5)]
```

The result should give me only 2 geometries that are actually equal.
But the result i got is only 1 geometry

```
**MULTILINESTRING((-0.87190 52.25757, -0.87185 52.25767, -0.87171 52.25775, -0.87151 52.25777, -0.87151 52.25777))**
```

How could this happen ?
is there any internal processing that doing wrong operation?
please help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my answer from GitHub.

`geoframe1.geom_almost_equals(geoframe2, decimal=5)` works row-wise. It aligns both GeoSeries and checks if geometries almost equal for each row.

In your case, the first checks with the first which is `True` since both are equal. Second checks with second, which is `False`, because they are different. Third checks with `None`.

Therefore you have `[True, False, False]` which naturally returns a single row.

Comment: Thank you martinfleis. till now , i am of the openion that each line of geoframe1 compare itself with all lines of geoframe2 (Like a nested for-loop)

Is there such function in geopandas that checks for actual geometric equality rather than row-wise?

Comment: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1678#issuecomment-723422890